# Is there a way to utilize Bcrypt for iOS development with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I have been searching for a library, cocoapod, or something else that allows me to implement Bcrypt in iOS using Swift.

Comment: Using an objective-c implementation with a bridging header in swift is one option.

Comment: You can check the link for bcrypt example("code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt"). It might be helpful.

http://vluxe.io/swift-web-api.html


  [1]: http://vluxe.io/swift-web-api.html

Comment: @Karlos are you sure that it can help anyhow? It's all about Go

Comment: @Bourne, I have found this https://github.com/dsibilly/bcrypt_objc, but I cannot get it to work…

Comment: @Serge Velikanov : Yes, It works fine in my project. If you want I can post a equivalent library or Objective C files in GitHub that can be used using Bridging-Header. But I can do that only on coming weekend.

Comment: @Serge Velikanov : Please find the link for 5 files from which you can achieve bcrypt. You need to do objective-c implementation with a bridging header in swift. Hope this will be helpful. https://gist.github.com/Kadasiddha/6a4dd7e9301ee516c5db

Comment: @Karlos, thank you for the answer. I've just used https://github.com/dsibilly/bcrypt_objc for my application and it is no problem. But my project is entirely in Objective C, didn't try this in Swift

Comment: If you are not locked into bcrypt consider PBKDF2 which is provided by Common Crypto. NIST is currently recommending PBKDF2 for hashing passwords for storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BCryptSwift](https://cocoapods.org/pods/BCryptSwift) - cocoapod written in Swift.

There is also a cocoapod [BCrypt](https://cocoapods.org/pods/BCrypt), it's actually a version used in the [Perfect](https://github.com/PerfectSideRepos/PerfectBCrypt) (Swift-serverside toolkit), but adopted to be used in iOS as a cocoa pod dependency.

Sample usage:

```
import BCrypt

let password = "mypassword"
do {
    let salt = try BCrypt.Salt()
    let hashed = try BCrypt.Hash(password, salt: salt)
    print("Hashed result is: \(hashed)")
}
catch {
    print("An error occured: \(error)")
}
```